# Exact number of characters in a JSON

Tags: python, json, character, readline

I have a file with several JSON objects in each line. And, I need to know the length of each object, I mean the each number of characters. But when I run the code below, it provides a number of characters less than expected.

```
jsonFile = open(File, 'r')
line = jsonFile.readline()
len(line)
```

It considers some elements like "/n" as a one character but I want it to say there are two. Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: Do you mean `\n`? That *is* one character.

Comment: `\n` *is* one character. It is a newline character. Python only shows you the character as an escape sequence in the `repr()` output, which is meant for debugging. Making non-printable characters is a helpful debugging tool.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here, really?

Comment: For offset purposes `\n` is one character. Also, why do you need a character offset in the file when you're using readline to get the contents?

Comment: @user3738070: but `readline()` automatically will read the next line. There is no need to use offsets here. And the *documented purpose* of the `.readline()` call is to return one line, so the `\n` character is the very last on the line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually, I have a file with several JSON objects representing tweets. I would like to automatically analyse each object (namely a tweet) in the file. To do so, I get the first JSON object thanks to readlines() and then I want to compute the exact number of elements (I use _len()_) in it so that I can set an offset at the end of the first object. But _len()_ doesn't provide the full number of elements in the JSON object.

Comment: @user3738070: did you perhaps want to *decode* the JSON to a Python object then? `len()` on that gives you the number of keys in the object.

Comment: @user3738070: or you could extract *just the text* of the tweet and call `len()` on that to get the number of characters *in the tweet itself* rather than the length of the JSON representation of the tweet with all the metadata...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you very much for your messages ! I didn't know how powerful was _readlines()_ ... My request has looked really useless. Thank you again for your time and help !

Answer (score 0):

```
print os.path.getsize('myfile.json')
```

http://devdocs.io/python/library/os.path#os.path.getsize